# Getting an error on Android 8 on a Samsung device using SCameraCaptureSession

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to capture a video using SCameraCaptureSession class. While using a function of this class - setRepeatingRequest (which described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#setRepeatingRequest(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler))), I'm getting the following error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!**

As I noticed, the problem is occurring because of something in the MediaRecorder's Surface object. However, it is working fine while using Android version older than 8 and the crash happens only on Samsung devices running Android 8.
No google search revealed anything useful about that crash, so I believe it is quite new...

Does anyone have any piece of information? How can I make that MediaRecorder's surface work fine on a device like I mentioned?

**Important note:** Capturing the video works **great** on any Android version before 8!!!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same the same issue.

Comment: Currently I'm still facing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is an issue with the surface configuration coming from MediaRecorder. If you pass a custom persistent surface, it should work.

1. Instantiate a surface by calling MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface()
2. Pass it using mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(yourSurface);
3. call yourSurface.release() after you stop using this surface.

NOTE: Do not use mediaRecorder.getSurface() if you decide to use this approach

REFERENCES:

MediaRecorder : [MediaRecorder - Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html)

MediaCodec:  [MediaCodec - Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception and I solved my case.
Root cause of my case is I had re-created Surface of TextureView.
When I change it not to re-created Surface, The exception was gone.

My code also works good before Android 8.0

My initializing camera is like following.

```
CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
CameraCaptureSession mCameraCaptureSession;
CaptureRequest mCaptureRequest;
Surface mTextureViewSurface;

public void updateCameraState(boolean run) {
    if (run) {
        if (mTextureView == null || !mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            // wait until mTextureView is available
            // then call updateCameraState() again via SurfaceTextureListener

            return;
        }
        if (mCameraDevice == null) {
            // open camera and wait until mCameraDevice is obtained.
            // then call updateCameraState() again via CameraDevice.StateCallback

            mCameraManager.openCamera(...);
            return;
        }
        if (mCameraCaptureSession == null) {
            // createCaptureSession and wait until mCameraCaptureSession is obtained.
            // then call updateCameraState() again via CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback

            mTextureViewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            List<Surface> surfaces = Arrays.asList(mTextureViewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface());
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, mSessionStateCallback, sHandler);
            return;
        }
        if (mCaptureRequest == null) {
            CaptureRequest.Builder builder = mCameraCaptureSession.getDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            /* Put some values into builder */

            // *************************************************************************
            // POINT: In my old code, It re-create Surface
            // *************************************************************************
            // Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            // builder.addTarget(surface);

            builder.addTarget(mTextureViewSurface);
            mCameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), mCaptureCallback, sHandler);
        }
        // fin
    } else {
        if (mCaptureRequest != null) {
            mCaptureRequest = null;
        }
        // *************************************************************************
        // POINT: I do not know release() is needed. But I add it here.
        // *************************************************************************
        if (mTextureViewSurface != null) {
            mTextureViewSurface.release();
            mTextureViewSurface = null;
        }
        if (mCameraCaptureSession != null) {
            mCameraCaptureSession.close();
            mCameraCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are offering to make some actions when some conditions are being met. But in my case they are never being met, so your solution cannot solve my problem. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this. I actually had the same issue. I had the line "previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(new Surface(mCameraTexture));" which created a new surface rather than reusing the old one. As such, I changed it to "previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(targetList.get(0));" where targetList is a list containing the previous surface at location 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms.
I solved using 'SurfaceView' class
but not used android.hardware.camera2
Using android.hardware.camera

Solved parts of codes.

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    // encoding data
    encoding(data) ;
}


/**
 * byte data encoding
 * @param data
 */
private void encoding (byte[] data) {
    // api 21 미만에 대해서 필요
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = this.mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = this.mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    int inputBufferIndex = this.mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC/* wait time, nagative value is infinite */);
    // data write 가능 할 경우
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        // data null (마지막 데이터)
        int length = 0, flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM;

        if (data != null) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = null;
            if (CameraUtils.isCamera2()) inputBuffer = this.mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
            else inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];

            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(data);

            length = data.length;
            flags = 0;
        }
        /*
         - index : dequeueInputBuffer 에서 return 받은 index 번호를 넣습니다.
         - offset : 항상 0이겠지만 Buffer에 채워넣은 데이터의 시작 점을 지정할 수 있습니다.
         - size : Buffer에 채워넣은 데이터 사이즈 정보
         - presentationTimeUs : 디코딩의 경우 Play 할 데이터의 시간(마이크로 초)
         - flags : 읽은 버퍼의 정보가 설정값인지 BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG, 마지막 데이터인지BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM에 대한 정보를 초기화 할 수 있습니다.
            대부분은 0을 채워넣고 마지막 데이터를 알리기 위해서는 BUFFER_FLAGS_END_OF_STREAM을 넣습니다.
         */
        this.mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, length, computePresentationTimeNsec(), flags);
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = this.mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC/* wait time, nagative value is infinite */);
    switch (outputBufferIndex) {
        /*
         MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED
         - Buffer 정보가 1번 변경되게 됩니다.
         - API 21인 Lollipop 부터는 이 @deprecated 되었기에 불필요하지만 이전 API에서는 꼭 필요한 정보입니다. 이게 호출되면 처음에 생성한 ByteBuffer[] 배열의 변화가 일어나게 됩니다.
         */
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
            Log.i(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
            outputBuffers = this.mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
            break;
         /*MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED
         - 처음에 생성하였든 MediaFormat을 기억하시는지요. 그 MediaFormat이 변경된 정보를 알려주게됩니다.
         - 이 경우는 Encoder에서만 주로 사용하고, 디코더에서는 사용할 일은 없습니다.
         */
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
            if (this.isMuxerStart) throw new RuntimeException("Format changed twice");
            Log.d(TAG, "INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED format : " + this.mediaCodec.getOutputFormat());

            this.trackId = this.mediaMuxer.addTrack(this.mediaCodec.getOutputFormat());
            this.mediaMuxer.start();
            this.isMuxerStart = true;
            break;
         /*MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER
         - 이 함수가 호출되는 경우라면 사실 무시하여도 됩니다.
         */
        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
            break;
         /*outputBufferIndex >= 0
         - 이 경우에 실제 디코딩 된 데이터가 들어오는 경우에 해당됩니다.
         */
        default:
            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0 && this.mediaCodec != null && this.mediaMuxer != null) {
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = null;
                if (CameraUtils.isCamera2()) outputBuffer = this.mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);
                else outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];

                // null exception
                if (outputBuffer == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("EncoderOutputBuffer " + outputBuffer + " was NULL");

                if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                    // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                    // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                    bufferInfo.size = 0;
                }

                if (bufferInfo.size >= 0) {
                    if (!this.isMuxerStart) throw new RuntimeException("MediaMuxer hasn't started");

                    // 프레임의 타임스탬프 작성
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = computePresentationTimeNsec();
                    this.prevTime = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
                    this.mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(this.trackId, outputBuffer, bufferInfo);
                }
                this.mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false/* true is surface init */);
                outputBufferIndex = this.mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC/* wait time, nagative value is infinite */);

                // end of frame
                if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    // release
                    releaseRecorder();
                    // 저장 완료
                    onCompleteEncoding(recordPath);
                    stopEncodingThread();
                    return;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate or at least give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem as yours. I only got it working after I used `SCameraProcessor` from Samsung's **SCamera SDK**.

I'd recommend that you download the sample APK that they offer and take a close look, but here's a snippet with the main parts that you need to pay more attention to:

Set up:

```
SCamera sCamera = new SCamera();
sCamera.initialize(this);
...
SCameraProcessorManager processorManager = sCamera.getSCameraProcessorManager();
SCameraEffectProcessor processor = processorManager
    .createProcessor(SCameraProcessorManager.PROCESSOR_TYPE_EFFECT);
...
processor.initialize();
...
// Carry out the opening process of the camera device here.
...
processor.setOutputSurface(outputSurface);
Surface cameraSurface = processor.getInputSurface();

// 'cameraSurface' above must then be added as a target to your
// SCaptureRequest.Builder and given as part of the surfaces list
// to have configured when calling SCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest().
```

Start recording:

```
// After setting up your MediaRecorder object...
processor.setRecordingSurface(mediaRecorder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Stop recording:

```
processor.setRecordingSurface(null);
mediaRecorder.stop();
mediaRecorder.reset();
```

References:

- Samsung developers home for Camera interaction: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera#
- API reference: http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/camera/index.html

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using androidx library i suggest to update to the last version of that library (1.0.0-alpha03) that should be resolve this issue as changelog said.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#1.0.0-alpha03

- Fixed unconfigured Input/Output Surface crash on rapid open/close or bind/unbind